# querying domino from php

Tags: php, database, lotus-domino

I've been tasked to extract data from a Domino and commit changes to it using PHP or web. I'm really new to Domino. I've been researching and it seems i must use urlcommands but i can't seem to find a way to directly extract/import data from Domino like a regular database. Another research of mine and i realized i need to code inside Designer, of which i don't have any idea how to extract/commit data.

Am i running around in circles? can somebody enlighten me..  thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL commands are simply the slightly odd domino url structure based on what seemed like a good idea in 1996.  They won't do anything unless there is an application (database) on the server that has been built to do what you want.

On a Domino server you will typically find that the database contains all the design elements and logic for the web application.  All the code is internal to the database and the developer builds the web application using features of domino, e.g. forms, views, agents etc.

A very simple application for entering data and viewing it may consist of a single form (domino design element, not html form) for entering and viewing documents and a single view for listing the documents that have been created.  These design elements would be created in Domino Designer and when the database was put on a server the documents created would also be stored in the same database.

It's possible to interact with the data from an external source using various APIs like the java api, or by interacting with a webservice that the domino application developer has provided.

Comment: how about shared connections? can i expose the database for other platform, say a web-based lang such as php? is it safe or it is safer to just open up web services?